# Do I always have to type package name in Java?

Tags: java, netbeans

Today I started learning Java.

I saw that package automatic gets included in .Java file. 
I was wondering if it always need to be included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider specify a common package for all the types within a same project.

In Java is common to start a project with a specific package setting. A package creates a namespace to disambiguate the types that it includes, to play nicelly with other projects that may or may not be in the same classpath. Normally, the package is bound to a URL of the project.

Think of Java packages like C++ namespaces.

A huge project/product written in Java can depend on lots and lots of projects, each described in a different package.

Organizations like Apache have lots of projects, organized under a common package pattern: `org.apache.<<name_of_the_project>>`.

Consider starting your project with a package named: `com.user3552670`; or something like your personal site, so persons that will consume your project can relate to the creator.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

It's used to specify the package of the class, [read more here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html).

You could create a class without a package, but your code will look bad..
They exists to avoid conflicts, example between your code and default java package.

If packages doesn't exists, you can't create a class named ArrayList because already exists in Java.

Some IDEs force the fact that, if your .java file is in `com/a/b/c` folder his package should be `com/a/b/c` (If i don't remember wrong, IntellIJ IDEA do that)

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

It must be there, but the IDE takes care of it (I don't use Netbeans, but I'd bet that it can do it, too). When moving files between packages, it has to be updated, but again, the IDE does it all.